# How to add Windows file path to .bib entry? (pandoc)

Tags: pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

#### Question

How would one add Windows file path with possible backslashes, underscores and spaces, such as

```
C:\My_fancy\document path\document.docx
```

to a .bib entry? I am using pandoc with [pandoc-citeproc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc) to create the pdf file.

#### MWE

Complete MWE to test the solution (all files in same folder)

**my_paper.md**

```
# Title

This is citation [@test_ref]
```

**references.bib**

```
@misc{test_ref,
    author={Test Author},
    year={2020},
    title = {Ultimate source of truth.},
}
```

**header.tex**

```
% any content to be added to preamble
```

**build command**

```
pandoc --include-in-header=header.tex  --filter pandoc-citeproc --metadata bibliography=references.bib --metadata reference-section-title=References my_paper.md -o my_paper.pdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the answer while trying to add all different ways to the question that did *not* work. The working solution was:

```
@misc{test_ref,
    author={Anonymous Author},
    year={1999},
    title = {A Title. Available at \url{C:\My_fancy\document path\with lots of spaces\document.docx}},
}
```

I will leave this as a reference, in case someone else faces the same problem.

Comment: Choose your answer as the correct answer.